# Using th:each with Twitter Bootstrap and multiple rows

Tags: thymeleaf

I am iterating over multiple addresses, and I want them in rows with 2 columns each.  The way to achieve this with Twitter Bootstrap would be something like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">First Address</div>
    <div class="span6">Second Address</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">Third Address</div>
    <div class="span6">Fourth Address</div>
</div>
```

I can't seem to get Thymeleaf to do this in a single th:each statement.  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break your array into chunks, based on the number of columns you want.  So, for two columns, you could do the following:

```
<div th:each="addressChunks : ${T(com.google.common.collect.Lists).partition(customerAddresses, 2)}" class="row-fluid">
    <div th:each="address : ${addressChunks}" th:object="${address}" class="span6">
        <address></address>
    </div>
</div>
```